# JS functions and abstract class and prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype

Here is a simplified version of my code :

```
  function TextBox () {
    this.builddom = function () {
      // Building the text dom
    }
  }
  function ImageBox () {
    this.builddom = function () {
      // Building the image dom
    }
  }
  function Box (type) {
    var handler =
      (type ==  'text') TextBox  :
      (type == 'Image') ImageBox : null;
    if (handler) (handler).call (this);

    this.builddom = function () {
      // Here I would like to call the correct builddom function for the type.
    }
  }
  var textbox = new Box ('text');
  textbox.builddom ();
```

If Box.builddom doesn't exists, this works fine, the builddom function associated with the specific type is called. But I need to do some general thing in Box and then call the specific builddom. If I give a different name to Box builddom, say Box.dobuilddom, it is fine too, but breaks generic access to Boxes.

I think some clever prototype manipulation can do the job, but I was unable to find it.

Comment: why are you not extending `Box` from the other 2 functions?

Comment: That's a very odd structure. You seem to want to make `new Box` return instances that inherit from `TextBox` or `ImageBox` based on the parameter to `Box`. That's *possible*, but frankly not a good idea.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I completely agree. It makes no sense from any abstraction perspective. In OOP you'd be using delegation ant actually passing `handler` directly instead of passing `type` and trying to figure out what `handler` to use based on that. Alternatively, you'd have a factory of some sort that returns you different boxes. There is very little reason to have `Box()` as is right now.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe would be better to avoid prototyping and **use composition** instead:

```js
function TextBox(box) {
  this.builddom = function() {    
    console.log('Building the text dom', box.props);
  }
}

function ImageBox(box) {
  this.builddom = function() {
    console.log('Building the image dom', box.props);
  }
}

function Box(props) {
  this.props = props;
  this.builddom = function() {
    throw new Error('unsupported function');
  }
}

var textbox = new TextBox(new Box({size:5}));
textbox.builddom();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the concept. The box is just some sort of container. It does not do anything but creates a new instance. What you'd really need here is a Box interface, but js does not have interfaces. You can use TypeScript if you want to...

```
  function TextBox () {
    this.builddom = function () {
      // Building the text dom
    }
  }
  function ImageBox () {
    this.builddom = function () {
      // Building the image dom
    }
  }

  var container = {
    createBox: function (type){
        if (type == "text")
            return new TextBox();
        else if (type == "image")
            return new ImageBox();
        else
            throw new Error();
    }
  };

  var textbox = container.createBox('text');
  textbox.builddom();
```

Another option is using proxy if you want to wrap objects, but I don't think that's your goal here.

If you need type check later, then you can use inheritance, but there is no multi inheritance, so even that way you cannot imitate interfaces. It goes this way btw.

```
  function Box (){}

  function TextBox () {}
  TextBox.prototype = Object.create(Box.prototype, {
    constructor:TextBox,
    builddom: function () {
      // Building the text dom
    }
  });

  function ImageBox () {}
  ImageBox.prototype = Object.create(Box.prototype, {
    constructor:ImageBox,
    builddom: function () {
      // Building the image dom
    }
  });

  var container = {
    createBox: function (type){
        if (type == "text")
            return new TextBox();
        else if (type == "image")
            return new ImageBox();
        else
            throw new Error();
    }
  };

  var textbox = container.createBox('text');
  console.log(
    textbox instanceof Box, 
    textbox instanceof ImageBox, 
    textbox instanceof TextBox
  );
  textbox.builddom();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use prototyping, you can smth like this:

```js
function TextBox(props) {
    this.props = props;
}

TextBox.prototype = {
    builddom: function () {
      // Building the text dom
      console.log("TextBox", this.props);
    }
}

function ImageBox(props) {
    this.props = props;
}

ImageBox.prototype = {
    builddom: function () {
      // Building the text dom
      console.log("ImageBox", this.props);
    }
}

function Box (type, props) {
  var handler = (type ==  'text') ? TextBox :
    (type == 'Image')  ? ImageBox : null;
  if (handler) {
     handler.call(this, props);
     Object.assign(this, handler.prototype);     
  }
}

var textbox = new Box ('text', {text: 'some'});
textbox.builddom ();

var imagebox = new Box ('Image', {x: 1, y: 2});
imagebox.builddom ();
```

Comment: Wow, just 1 hour and many answers. I'll clarify somewhat. Actually, the TextBox and ImageBox are not supposed to be written by me. The Box function is part of a toolkit, other developers should create xxxBoxes with the constraint to expose a builddom method (and many others). The toolkit offers some kind of Box registration to be able to use this new type of Box. This the perfect case for 'interface' or 'abstract class' use in Java. I'd better use the JS 'class' feature but is is not yet usable in all browser.

Comment: Sorry for the interrupted comment, I didn't realize that hitting the Enter key sends it immediately. So... All my code refers only to the Box function. The others xxxBoxes can refer to it too. For instance TextBoxes can use ImageBoxes. That the reason to offer a single interface to all boxes. I hope is is more clear. Claude.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a box class if you are not going to use it, instead create a factory function and return a new instance of the respective class.

```js
function AbstractBox() {}
AbstractBox.prototype.builddom = function() {
  console.warn("unimplemented method");
};

function TextBox() {}
TextBox.prototype.builddom = function() {
  console.log("TextBox.builddom called");
};

function ImageBox() {}
ImageBox.prototype.builddom = function() {
  console.log("ImageBox.builddom called");
};

function ErrorBox() {}



function createBox(type) {
  var handler = Object.create(({
    "text": TextBox,
    "Image": ImageBox
  }[type] || ErrorBox).prototype);
  handler.constructor.apply(handler, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
  for (var property in AbstractBox.prototype) {
    var method = AbstractBox.prototype[property];
    if (typeof method === "function" && !(property in handler)) handler[property] = method;
  }
  return handler;
}

(createBox("text")).builddom(); // Text
(createBox("Image")).builddom(); // Image
(createBox("error")).builddom(); // Error
```

Comment: I do use the Box class, actually, this is the only class I use to access Boxes. The TextBox and ImageBox are just here for the Box class to encapsulate them. I have a solution, it is to use different names for builddom, say builddom in Box and dombuild il all xxxBox implementation, this not very clean and should be avoidable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you don't just use standard prototype inheritance here. It will allow you to both inherit or override methods of the parent. For example, `ImageBox` inherits the parent method and `TextBox` overrides:

```js
/* Define Box */
function Box (type) {
    this.type = type || 'box'
}
Box.prototype.builddom = function (){
    console.log(this.type, ": build called")
}

/* Define TextBox */
function TextBox () {
    Box.call(this, "text")
}
TextBox.prototype = Object.create(Box.prototype);

/* Override method */
TextBox.prototype.builddom = function (){
    // call parent method too?
    // Box.prototype.builddom.call(this)
    console.log(this.type, "Text box override method")
}

/* Define ImageBox */
function ImageBox () {
    Box.call(this, "image")
}
ImageBox.prototype = Object.create(Box.prototype);


var box = new Box ();
box.builddom();

var textbox = new TextBox ();
textbox.builddom();

var imageBox = new ImageBox ();
imageBox.builddom();
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use composition/delegation rather than inheritance (has-a instead of is-a).

```
function TextBox () {
    this.builddom = function () {
      // Building the text dom
    }
  }
  function ImageBox () {
    this.builddom = function () {
      // Building the image dom
    }
  }
  function Box (type) {
    var constructor =
      (type ==  'text') ? TextBox  :
      (type == 'Image') ? ImageBox : null;
    var delegate = new constructor();

    this.builddom = function () {
      // Pre-work goes here.
      delegate.builddom();
      // Post-work goes here.
    }
  }
  var textbox = new Box ('text');
  textbox.builddom ();
```